# Funciones definidas por el usuario | Curiosidad

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos

ahora entrando a las funciones me encuentro con este Ejercicio. Si lo pude resolver pero tengo una Duda y Me gustaría que me retroalimentaran de información.

### **Consultar el número de usuarios de cada ciudad, pero solo de una ciudad específica**

Mis tablas son;
Usuario:

````
```  CREATE TABLE USUARIO(
IDUSUARIO INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY ,
IDCIUDAD INT REFERENCES CIUDAD(IDCIUDAD),
NOMBRES VARCHAR(50),
DIRECCION VARCHAR (100),
TELEFONO INT,
EMAIL VARCHAR(100),
PASSWORD VARCHAR(50)) ```
````

Ciudad:

````
```  CREATE TABLE CIUDAD(
IDCIUDAD INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
NOMCIUDAD VARCHAR(50))  ```
````

Insertar datos:

`````
```` INSERT INTO [dbo].[CIUDAD]
           ([NOMCIUDAD])
     VALUES
           ('MILAGRO'),('GUAYAQUIL'),('DURAN'),
           ('LOJA'),('CUENCA')
GO```
`````

Usuario:

````
```INSERT INTO [dbo].[USUARIO]
           ([IDCIUDAD]
           ,[NOMBRES]
           ,[DIRECCION]
           ,[TELEFONO]
           ,[EMAIL]
           ,[PASSWORD])
     VALUES
           (5,'EDGAR','CHIRIJOS',0994689633,'EDGAR@.COM','MUNDOBOB'),
           (2,'LEO','AMAZONAS',0994689633,'LEO@.COM','LEO2'),
           (5,'NICOLAS','PASTAZA',0994689633,'NICO@.COM','123456'),
           (1,'TERESA','AV.CHILE',0994689633,'TERE@.COM','ELEFANTE234'),
           (4,'LIL UZI','BRONZ',0994689633,'UZI@.COM','RAPLIFE'),
           (3,'MARIA BELEN','EIWA',0994689633,'BELEN@COM','2022MESA')
GO ```
````

La función Que realice:
(Esta si funciona)

````
``` CREATE FUNCTION CONSUL12 (
@CIUDAD VARCHAR(50) ) 
RETURNS TABLE
AS

    RETURN ( 
    SELECT CIUDAD.NOMCIUDAD,COUNT(USUARIO.IDUSUARIO) AS TOTAL FROM CIUDAD INNER JOIN
    USUARIO ON USUARIO.IDCIUDAD = CIUDAD.IDCIUDAD WHERE CIUDAD.NOMCIUDAD = @CIUDAD
    GROUP BY CIUDAD.NOMCIUDAD)

SELECT * FROM CONSUL12('CUENCA') ```
````

En esta función todo bien Ahora viene mi duda. Antes de hacer esa hice una igual pero con una diferencia. Le había puesto el Begin End. Tal que así.

````
``` CREATE FUNCTION CONSUL13 (
@CIUDAD VARCHAR(50) ) 
RETURNS TABLE
AS
Begin
    RETURN ( 
    SELECT CIUDAD.NOMCIUDAD,COUNT(USUARIO.IDUSUARIO) AS TOTAL FROM CIUDAD INNER JOIN
    USUARIO ON USUARIO.IDCIUDAD = CIUDAD.IDCIUDAD WHERE CIUDAD.NOMCIUDAD = @CIUDAD
    GROUP BY CIUDAD.NOMCIUDAD)
End
SELECT * FROM CONSUL13('CUENCA') ```
````

**Ahora mi pregunta es la siguiente. Porque cuando le pongo el Begin y End. no funciona y sale error? Porque antes hice otra función donde si le puse begin y end y no me dio problemas. ¿En que casos nomas se usa el begin y porque en este no se pudo realizar?
si desean corregir mi código para aprender hacerlo de una manera mas correcta o practica estaría agradecido :D**

Comment: ¿Y porque va a funcionar, si le has puesto algo que no corresponde? Las funciones tipo table-inline, no llevan begin ni end. Además tienen que ser las únicas instrucciones de un lote. Por tanto después de return llevan una select o un with.... y entre paréntesis. Las funciones tipo userDefined o las funciones escalares si llevan Begin y End, y no son las unicas instrucciones de la función por tanto puedes poner más cosas. Son cosas diferentes. Y como ya te he comentado otra vez. Sale error, y no funciona, son conceptos que no interesan. Solo interesa el error explicito.

Comment: Si estas estudiando SQL Server, no deberías de introducir etiquetas que no tienen nada que ver, como `sqlLIte` e incluso algunas otras, porque no te aportan valor a tí ni al foro. Un programador de Oracle, no te va a aportar conocimiento, en que ocurre entre un begin y un end en TSQL, porque son diferentes. Si te puede aportar en una select por ejemplo.

Answer (score 0):

No funciona porque son dos tipos de funciones distintas. Las funciones tipo tabla en linea tienen una sintaxis y funcionamiento más similar a una vista que recibe parámetros que al resto de las funciones. También existen las funciones tipo tabla de múltiples instrucciones y que sí usan `BEGIN...END` como las funciones escalares.

Por cuestiones de rendimiento, siempre es recomendable buscar una función en línea que una que use múltiples instrucciones.

Para que te des una idea, tu función

```
CREATE FUNCTION CONSUL12 (
    @CIUDAD VARCHAR(50) 
) 
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN  
    SELECT C.NOMCIUDAD,
            COUNT(U.IDUSUARIO) AS TOTAL 
    FROM CIUDAD AS C
    INNER JOIN USUARIO AS U ON U.IDCIUDAD = C.IDCIUDAD 
    WHERE C.NOMCIUDAD = @CIUDAD
    GROUP BY C.NOMCIUDAD;
```

Puede correr unas 10 veces más rápido que la alternativa que usa `BEGIN...END`

```
CREATE FUNCTION CONSUL12 (
    @CIUDAD VARCHAR(50) 
) 
RETURNS @UsuariosCiudad TABLE ( 
            NOMCIUDAD varchar(100),
            TOTAL     int)
AS
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO @UsuariosCiudad(
        NOMCIUDAD,
        TOTAL)
    SELECT C.NOMCIUDAD,
            COUNT(U.IDUSUARIO) AS TOTAL 
    FROM CIUDAD AS C
    INNER JOIN USUARIO AS U ON U.IDCIUDAD = C.IDCIUDAD 
    WHERE C.NOMCIUDAD = @CIUDAD
    GROUP BY C.NOMCIUDAD;

    RETURN;
END
```